# Meaning of "mad" and "bomb" as adjectives in Ant Man

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

At the end of Ant-Man (2015), Michael Peña's character Luis delivers a typical rambling story to Scott Lang (Paul Rudd):

The scene can be seen from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYUFx_Ltjn8). The following are the transcripts from [wiki](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man):

> **Luis:** Okay. Sorry, sorry. I’m ju… you know, uh, I just get excited and
>   stuff. But anyway, anyway. When Ignacio tells me: “Yoh, I met this
>   crazy fine writer chick at this spot last night. Like, fine, fine,
>   crazy stupid fine.” And he goes up to the bartender and goes: “Look at
>   the girl I’m with? You know what I’m sayin’? She’s crazy stupid fine,
>   right?” [we see flashback to Ignacio meeting the girl and talking to
>   the bartender who is in fact Stan Lee] And the bartender’s all like:
>   “Yeah, crazy stupid fine.” So this writer chick tells Ignacio: “Yoh,
>   I’m like a boss in the world of guerrilla journalism, and I got **mad**
>   connects with the peeps behind the curtains. You know what I’m
>   sayin’?” Ignacio’s like: “For real? And she’s like: Yeah. You know
>   what, I can’t tell you who my contact is, because he works with the
>   Avengers.”
>
> **Scott Lang:** Oh, no.
>
> **Luis:** Yeah, and this dude sounds like a bad-ass, man. Like he comes up
>   to her and says… [we see flashback of the girl meting up with Sam
>   Wilson in a park] “Yoh, I’m looking for this dude who’s no one seen,
>   who’s **flashing this fresh tack**, who’s got, like, **bomb moves**, right?
>   Who you got? She’s like: “Well, we got everything nowadays, we got a
>   guy who jumps, we got a guy who swings, we got a guy who crawls up the
>   walls. You gotta be more specific.” And he’s like: “I’m looking for a
>   guy who shrinks.” And I’m like: “Damn!” [to Scott] I got all nervous
>   cause I keep **mad** secrets for you, bro. So I asked Ignacio: “Did
>   bad-ass tell the stupid fine writer chick to tell you to tell me
>   because I’m tight with that man, that he’s looking for him?”
>
> **Scott Lang:** And? What’d he say?
>
> **Luis:** He said yes.

I don't quite understand these slangish expressions. I think the contextual meaning of **mad** is close to **real, serious**.

**Bomb moves** seems to me to literally mean unusual moves.

Comment: While I understand why these sections of the movie are really difficult for a learner to understand, I don't think this is on-topic here. There are a lot of questions about things here that are unrelated except for they're all slang. This is a translation request in my opinion.

Comment: Nope, it's a meaning request in my book. :-) @ColleenV

Comment: One meaning request? http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/767/should-we-mark-questions-containing-multiple-sub-questions-as-too-broad-until There are multiple meaning requests in there - they need to be split into individual questions.

Comment: *mad* ~ a lot; *bomb* ~ cool; I'm not sure about *tack* though.

Comment: Edited; @ColleenV

Comment: Wow! You are such an early bird. :) @DamkerngT.

Comment: I think this should be on-topic.  What a fun question! :-)

Comment: Thank you, ma'am :) BTW, I think it's too trivial to open a new question for that "tack" part. If you would take a look at the youtube link, could you tell me it's tack or tat(oo)? @snailboat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mad is closer to "unbelievable" or "surprising" here. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mad) has this for a few categories where I'd see this as similar to "mad skills" personally.

> I got unbelievable connections
>
> I got amazing connections

[Bomb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bomb) is similar as "something very cool/ good"